# API working well on POSTMAN but giving error in Curl PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, php-curl

I am trying to fetch the record from the api. It's working correctly on postman but giving the error when I use curl in php.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
    function GETAPISRecord(){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json?$where=provider_number in("017000","017037","017055","017056","017116","017319","017324"),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if($debug){
        // dd($url);
        dd($response);
    }
    return json_decode($response, true);

}
```

Here is the error I am getting after curl:
[error after curl option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCBaZ.png)

On the Postman it's giving the result perfect as expected:
[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BYT1.png)

Furthermore api [url](https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json)  working perfect without any parameters on search. it is also working fine if we use the zip_code filter like this [zipcode filter](https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json?zip=36104)   the only issue is with **$where=provider_number in("017000","017037","017055","017056","017116","017319","017324")**

If any body know how to solve this issue in Laravel way he can also answer this question.

Edit: Adding Curl headers that is in postman
[curl 7 headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ0wn.png)

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: The postman request shows that you have 7 headers set for the request, in curl you only set 2, what are the other 5? Might help if you show a screenshot of all the request details from postman

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to encode the url like `CURLOPT_URL => urlencode ( 'https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json?$where=provider_number in("017000","017037","017055","017056","017116","017319","017324")')`

Comment: @WesleySmith just added those 7 headers you can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issue because of url that i was providing. I should avoid the spaces and replace them with %20 and commas (") to %22 in the curl api

url should be like this: **https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json?$where=provider_number%20in(%22017000%22,%22017037%22,%22017055%22,%22017056%22,%22017116%22,%22017319%22,%22017324%22)**

In php way my curl will be like this:

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://data.medicare.gov/resource/6jpm-sxkc.json?$where=provider_number%20in(%22017000%22,%22017037%22,%22017055%22,%22017056%22,%22017116%22,%22017319%22,%22017324%22)",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cookie: _frontend_session=Sld3TFdrNEFIWmpJRnV4a2JveHpDc3F3T3dHd1lpak5idzByL1VVTHNQSEpSU2hlNEZxRDlPbjd1cG1TNzVyaVRERzg4ZGNDYkZCV1h3TXBlNWE3a1JRWnU0dTN3R2dMa3JST0xObVhjM2ZoMGlJZk5MN211Qkxtb3ErSmZ6OGVPZFBwc2tJVDJwQXRwQllrVXloQUFBPT0tLThZeHZZYk9SL3IzMUU3aU16RUordXc9PQ%3D%3D--e3eb18669fa6c2e905a40ffff0c33b559e0e241b; ak_bmsc=745EECBD67F7301E4B7311809DFAE6DC68788BC621610000997F775F7DEE2B48~plyfmyJzyR+AfIF/Np8ucZmQIrMNlYOCjSqJWkFlzOJaVhe+8AtA+XDOYdtvT0/tRLH+xgXE8bRjqc+SfoLVQ+1/26CLzz6LKnTKHrki68a5GB42zBY1YR2CaW/pyJyyK/2ByXsuKfPYfRj94udk+L1LAX0ksKnKIvcYURkPjwo8gMJpTaPb7l6IbBxAQWX2S6izEKTsaKo+ZlUHLKmMG60anU3k1DvNs50YhrvgppYUc=; bm_sv=3283155D1D2681C3CB7F831A5C8E51EB~tPx4bluLNUcZLdNKSDT9178Ehspi63N1nZIElfhOt/SoHh97ihVROaVGwOseGzU3yfYzOhRmau/0Zde2PJAx5OISYkav8uPzxD1biUDX7vPYDFQXPlcbyz3Q0XoWQjfhS0FLXxnkkw5RMUQ+3ZwnxbIAyVGL/eebL6R8LE3wT/8="
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

GoodLuck

Comment: ```urlencode``` is your friend https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Yeah, it's easy approach to encode your url. Thanks